# How to pass selected value from selectOneRadio tag to fileUpload tag in PrimeFaces

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0. I used selectOneRadio tag and populates the list from database, and then I would like to use the selected value to identify the type of document selected and pass this to fileUploadListener so that the right document type is attached to file being uploaded. How do I pass that selected value?

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="docType" value="#{fileUploadBean.docType}" layout="grid" columns="1">
   <f:selectItems var="document" value="#{fileUploadBean.docDescriptionList}" itemLabel="#{docType}" itemValue="#{docType}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:fileUpload id="docFile" value="#{fileUploadBean.file}" mode="advanced" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.uploadFile}" multiple="true" update="messages">
</p:fileUpload>

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass it to the fileUpload TAG? You should 'just' send it to the bean (e.g. by using ajax in it)...

Comment: @Kukeltje, I tried passing it to the bean using <p:ajax event="change"> when the user select an item but the value doesn't hold when I uploaded a file afterwards.

Comment: Then check the scopes of your beans

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I used ViewScoped and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add variable for allowed types and then update it when radio button is changed:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="docType" 
                  value="#{fileUploadBean.docType}"
                  layout="grid"
                  columns="1">
    <p:ajax listener="#{fileUploadBean.updateAllowTypes}" update="@form" />
    <f:selectItems var="document" 
                   value="#{fileUpoadBean.docDescriptionList}"
                   itemLabel="#{docType}"
                   itemValue="#{docType}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:fileUpload id="docFile" 
              value="#{fileUploadBean.file}" 
              mode="advanced" 
              allowTypes="#{fileUploadBean.allowTypes}"
              fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.uploadFile}" 
              multiple="true" 
              update="messages">
</p:fileUpload>
```

And in Java bean:

```
private String allowTypes; //getters and setters
...
public void updateAllowTypes(){
    allowTypes = ... //Specify allowed types
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it's not really working like what I'm hoping for. I'm not trying to change the allowTypes value, I still want only pdf files, but what I meant was, the radio button would list the type of documents, such as "certificates", "resume", and based on the selection, the file uploaded will be filed under "certificates" or "resumes".